# How can I transform a signal into another using supervised learning?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, time-series, supervised-learning, signal-processing

I'm trying to transform a signal into another using supervised learning. My main goal is to create a model capable to transform a raw signal (Blue Line) into something similar to the "ideal" one (Green Line).

This is what I have done right now:[image]
And these are the results:[image]

Since my model has to operate online, the signals, are divided in moving windows. Also, my model take as input the blue line and has to output something like the green line, but as you can see is not working at all.

I tried with different layers, like Conv1D, Dense and may other, but is not working.

- Do you have any suggestion?
- Do you know why my model, everytime it is making a prediction (red line) always start with a peak?

Comment: Please, don't provide screenshots, because they make it difficult to refer to specific statements in the code. Just copy and paste the relevant code. However, note that programming questions are off-topic. Code should only be provided if it helps to understand the problem or question. Thanks.